# blogdown index.Rmd uses `:::` instead of `::` to specify package, Why?

Tags: r, blogdown

I noticed the `/index.Rmd` R blogdown file contains three colons `:::` instead of the two `::` I'm used to seeing (eg `dplyr::filter`).

```
---
site: blogdown:::blogdown_site
---
```

Why the three semicolons? And why doesn't `?blogdown::blogdown_site` or `?blogdown:::blogdown_site` come up with anything?

Comment: Did you take a look at the R documentation: [Double Colon and Triple Colon Operators](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/ns-dblcolon.html)?

Comment: ::: is used to access a non exported function.